# CSS making each section of the form to be placed horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a way to make a css to separate the long form into blocks and place them horizontally on the page.  Right now it's a vertical form and I have to scroll down to see the bottom section so I was thinking if it's possible to place each section horizontally on the page.  How should I do this?

**CSS Code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, h1, form, fieldset, legend, ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #FC0;
    color: #111111;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}

/*Form Steps Counter*/
form#newcust > fieldset > legend:before {
    content: "Step " counter(fieldsets) ": ";
    counter-increment: fieldsets;
}
/*Form*/
form#newcust {
    background: #9cbc2c;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    width: 400px;

}

/*Fieldset*/
form#newcust fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
form#newcust fieldset:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*Legend*/
form#newcust legend {
    color: #384313;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c0d576;
}

form#newcust ol li {
    background: #b9cf6a;
    border-color: #e3ebc3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
form#newcust ol ol li {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

form#newcust label {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 150px;
}
form#newcust fieldset fieldset label {
    background:none no-repeat left 50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    width: auto;
}
form#newcust fieldset fieldset label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*Input*/
form#newcust input:not([type=radio]),
form#newcust textarea {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font: 14px "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 200px;
}
form#newcust input:not([type=submit]):focus,
form#newcust textarea:focus {
    background: #eaeaea;
}
form#newcust input[type=radio] {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
form#newcust button {
    background: #384313;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font: 16px "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
form#newcust button:hover {
    background: #1e2506;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<body>
<form id=newcust method="POST" action="newcust.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Date</legend>
        <ol><li>
                <label for=purchase_date>Purchase Date:</label>
                <input id=purchase_date name=purchase_date type=date placeholder="Debenture's Purchase Date" required autofocus><br></li>
                <li><label for=mature>Maturity Date:</label>
                <input id=mature_date name=mature_date type=date placeholder="Debenture's Maturity Date" required><br></li>         
        </ol>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>General Information</legend>
        <ol>
                <li><label for=sub_id>Subscription No.:</label>
                <input id=sub_id name=sub_id required><br></li>
                <li><label for=cert_id>Certificate No.:</label>
                <input id=cert_id name=cert_id type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=amount>Principle:</label>
                <input id=amount name=amount type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=unit>Unit:</label>
                <input id=unit name=unit type=text required><br></li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Purchaser Information</legend>
        <ol>            
                <li><label for=purchaser_first>Purchaser First Name:</label>
                <input id=purchaser_first name=purchaser_first type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=purchaser_last>Purchaser Last Name:</label>
                <input id=purchaser_last name=purchaser_last type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=purchaser_id>Purchaser ID No.:</label>
                <input id=purchaser_id name=purchaser_id type=text  required><br></li>
                <li><label for=purchaser_no>Purchaser Phone No.:</label>
                <input id=purchaser_no name=purchaser_no type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=purchaser_add>Purchaser Address:</label>
                <textarea id=purchaser_add name=purchaser_add rows=5 required></textarea>
                <br></li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Beneficiary Information</legend>
        <ol>            
                <li><label for=beneficiary_first>Beneficiary First Name:</label>
                <input id=beneficiary_first name=beneficiary_first type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=beneficiary_last>Beneficiary Last Name:</label>
                <input id=beneficiary_last name=beneficiary_last type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=beneficiary_id>Beneficiary ID No.:</label>
                <input id=beneficiary_id name=beneficiary_id type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=beneficiary_no>Beneficiary Phone No.:</label>
                <input id=beneficiary_no name=beneficiary_no type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=beneficiary_add>Beneficiary Address:</label>
                <textarea id=beneficiary_add name=beneficiary_add rows=5 required></textarea><br></li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Bank Information</legend>
        <ol>            
                <li><label for=bank_acc_name>Bank Account Name:</label>
                <input id=bank_acc_name name=bank_acc_name type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=bank_acc_no>Bank Account No.:</label>
                <input id=bank_acc_no name=bank_acc_no type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=bank_swift>Bank Swift Code:</label>
                <input id=bank_swift name=bank_swift type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=bank_name>Bank Name:</label>
                <input id=bank_name name=bank_name type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=bank_no>Bank Phone No.:</label>
                <input id=bank_no name=bank_no type=text required><br></li>
                <li><label for=bank_add>Bank Address:</label>
                <textarea id=bank_add name=bank_add rows=5 required></textarea><br></li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <br>
        <button type=submit>Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fieldset { display: inline-block ; } ` ?

Comment: **Off topic:** First of all, you should place every attribute value in your HTML in between quotation marks, or at least apostrophes. F.e. `id=newcust` should become `id="newcust"`. Second, if possible, place your CSS in a separate file. Makes your code cleaner. 
**On topic:** You can make the `li`'s `display: inline`, or use `float:left` as you did, but keep in mind how wide the elements can be to appear next to each other. If you give them `width: 50%` for example, you can't add any margin or padding.

Comment: @Dreamonic To solve the float and margin problem, put the element you want to be "floated" inside a floating div with width 50%, then add margin or padding to the inside block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` and `ol` are **block level** elements. The `li` is also a **block level** element by inheritance.

You need to set `float: left` to change the `li`s default behavior in order to place them horizontally.
Then make the form `width` larger. Also adjust `width`s of the individual `label`s and `input`s to match the desired format.

Comment: I am seeing the lable and input being set to the left, but what i was saying is to make for example:  `date` as 1 part starting from the left then `general info` block will be placed to the right of date then `personal information` block on the right of `general info` and so on...

Comment: Yes, for every block you need to `clear: both` in order to achieve that design.